# Browserify-ed code on a server: how to get "window", "location" and other "window" properties and typically browser objects?

Tags: javascript, browserify, reactjs

I want to use browserified code both, in a browser and on a server. My code is basically React components. I want to browserify the code, get one compiled sheet `app.js` and use it both, in a browser and on a server:

```
// in a browser
<script src="/js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async></script>

// on a server
var App = require('../assets/js/react/app');
```

But browserify doesn't know `window` object as I understand. I cannot `require` browserified code in a server side, an error is thrown:

```
if (window.location.pathname == '/foo') {
    ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Here is code:

```
... many React components go here ...

// and here is a call to window and its properties
if(window.location.pathname == '/foo') {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <MsgBox data={window.data} oInfo={window.oInfo} />,
        document.getElementById('content-body')
    );

    ReactDOM.render(
        <SearchBox />,
        document.getElementById('searchBox')
    );
}
```

[browserify-handbook](https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#global) says that `global` is an alias for the `window`:

> In node, `global` is the top-level scope where global variables are attached similar to how `window` works in the browser. In browserify, `global` is just an alias for the `window` object.

I tried to change but then get another error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined`:

```
// the code, I change window to global
if(global.location.pathname == '/foo') {
    ...
}

// and an error
if (global.location.pathname == '/foo') {
                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
```

So how to deal with `window` in such a case?

One thought is to use a variable, which I do now:

```
var isBrowser;
if(typeof window != 'undefined') {
    isBrowser = true
}
else 
    isBrowser = false;
```

But is it the best way? It looks a little bit odd to me. Is there special means in Browserify for `window` and other native browsers only objects? What is the best practice to use Browserify in such a case?

Comment: When this code errors: `global.location.pathname` is that when running on the client or server? Have you tried setting a breakpoint there and seeing what `global` is?

Comment: @CodingWithSpike, an error with `global.location.pathname` is thrown on the server. On the server `global` is some OS global object. It has `env` variables, node `process`, `path` variable, all OS staff. But in a browser `global` is `Window` object. And it has a `location` property.

Comment: That makes sense then. The server doesn't have a 'location' because it isn't a browser with a URL.

Answer (score 5):

You are going to have trouble doing it that way.

It reminds me of Delphi's runtime / design-time packages that contain a lot of

```
if (state in csDesigning) do 
begin 
    ... // Bad juju 
end
else do 
begin
    ... // Bad juju
end
```

Not a good idea. You'll lose your mind in the long run. Instead, create a shared kernel that will contain your shared code, nothing else. The window variable should never be seen by the server.

```
browser.js
common.js // shared kernel (browserify)
server.js
```

Comment: I did so. Works fine. Thanks. However browserify-ed code disturbs me a little bit. Browserify is a powerful tool, but it generates some strange unwieldy code. Which makes me think whether that code slows down page rendering, server-side React rendering, and even user interaction on the page. It is not a question, though, just thoughts. Maybe I'll create another question about it.

Comment: The goal of browserify is exactly the opposite : so that you don't have to manage unwieldy code. It bundles everything up in a single .js file, (with a .map file if you wish), so that you can use it seamlessly in your browser, the same way you use it in node.. It's certainly not unwieldy to me :-) !

Answer (score 1):

Browser and server are different environments and some concepts don't exist on server side, such as **location**. So the problem is: what are you actually trying to get by accessing `global.location`?

If you want to know the pathname of the request, you should retrieve request url from http **requests** your server received. And that varies across different requests, so it cannot be a global parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using the `jsdom` package. https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom